# AOP Dependency Issue in Spring 4.3.4

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I'm currently using Spring 4.3.4 to execute a "Simple Aspect Example program". I tried using both XML and Annotation but it gives me BeanCreationException error.

> Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator'

I've added below mentioned dependencies:

- spring-core 4.3.4
- spring-beans 4.3.4
- spring-context 4.3.4
- spring-aspects 4.3.4

**Main:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/sonyx64/spring/aop/config/Beans.xml");
        Camera camera = (Camera) context.getBean("camera");
        camera.snap();
        context.close();
    }}
```

**Camera Class:**

```
public class Camera {
    public void snap() {
        System.out.println("SNAP!");
    }
}
```

**Logger Class:**

```
public class Logger {
    public void aboutToTakePhoto() {
        System.out.println("About To Take Photo");
    }
}
```

**Beans.xml**

```
<bean id="camera" class="com.sonyx64.spring.aop.Camera"></bean>
    <bean id="logger" class="com.sonyx64.spring.aop.Logger"></bean>
    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut expression="execution(void com.sonyx64.spring.aop.Camera.snap())"
            id="camerasnap" />
        <aop:aspect id="loggeraspect" ref="logger">
            <aop:before method="aboutToTakePhoto" pointcut-ref="camerasnap" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
```

Please suggest me an appropriate solution to deal with this exception.

Comment: Please show some actual code: Java application code, aspect(s), Spring and AOP configuration (XML or annotation-based). This is StackOverflow, not a quiz show. ;-)

Comment: Please share you're opinion.

Comment: @kriegaex It works when i modified the aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar (comes with spring-aspects maven package) with aspectjweaver-1.5.4.jar in POM file.

Comment: 1.5.4 is way too old, you should not do that.

Comment: Are you using compile time weaving? Load-time weaving? Are you even using AspectJ or you're using Spring AOP instead?

Answer (score 2):

The AspectJ weaver version is not the cause of your problem. I just tried, using your code and your POM. No matter if I use weaver 1.8.8 or 1.8.9 or if I completely remove the dependency from the POM, it works beautifully in all cases. So your own answer is wrong, unfortunately.

After you have uploaded your project to Google Drive, I could easily see the problem's root cause: You have a **Maven problem**. You do not use the standard Maven directory layout in order to make Maven find resources such as *beans.xml* in directory *src/main/resources*. Just check *target/classes* and the JAR created by Maven: no *beans.xml* in there. So please just fix your directory layout to look something like this:

[image: Maven directory layout]

This is what I did, also removing the `<sourceDirectory>` directive from the POM. Alternatively, you could set a custom resources directory by configuring Maven Resources Plugin.

---

P.S.: Next time please post your full stack trace, not just part of the error message. Or at least read your own error messages. ;-) There you have it very clearly (I deliberately added some line breaks):

```
INFORMATION: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/pop/spring/aop/Beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
    IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/pop/spring/aop/Beans.xml];
    nested exception is
        java.io.FileNotFoundException:
            class path resource [com/pop/spring/aop/Beans.xml]
            cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: I don't think that this could be the hitch. Because I'm using

`ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/pop/spring/aop/Beans.xml");`


And there is no problem in loading the context and i never faced this xml load error. You can clearly see in the attached LOG file  

`Error creating bean with name 'camera' defined in class path resource [com/pop/spring/aop/Beans.xml]:` 
this means context is loaded successfully and failed to create a bean named _camera_.

Comment: But this is what I see when I import your Eclipse project and run `Main` from the IDE. How do you start your application? P.S.: I am sure your directory layout is wrong in combination with the POM. It may work from an IDE, but surely not from the JAR.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Eclipse IDE. I simply do "Run as Application" from Main.java file.

Comment: With my setup documented here it works in Eclipse Neon as well as IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.3 while with yours it does not. But I am getting tired of trying to convince you that I have solved your problem. I did it for free anyway, so it cannot be worth a lot, I guess. (Have you even tried my suggestion?) Buena suerte, amigo!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same example what I did first I created the maven project and secondly for aspect weavers dependencies I have added the exclusion for the 1.8.8 version of aspectjweaver and included aspectjweaver 1.8.9 version and it worked.

Comment: This answer is wrong, see [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41422418/1082681). I tried and it worked with both versions. I also explained what was really wrong here. You must have had another problem.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the particular version of maven repository jar "aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar".
Running with the previous version 1.8.8 solved the issue.

**POM.xml:**

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <properties>
    <maven.target.source>1.8</maven.target.source>
    <maven.target.compiler>1.8</maven.target.compiler>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Hard to imagine (thus hard to believe) why 1.8.8 would work if 1.8.9 does not because the latter is just a minor bugfix release for the former. I assume that you also changed something else. Can you please elaborate on your environment? Java version, Spring version etc. What does your POM look like?

Comment: And now if you change 1.8.8 to 1.8.9 and nothing else(!), the error reoccurs? I am asking in this penetrant way because I really want to make sure. If that was really the case, you might have found a bug in AspectJ or hit upon an incompatibility issue which is, as I said, hard to imagine.

Comment: As I thought: The AspectJ weaver version is not the cause of your problem. I just tried, using exactly your code and your POM. No matter if I use weaver 1.8.8 or 1.8.9 or if I completely remove the dependency from the POM, it works beautifully in all cases. So your own answer is **wrong**. Please find out which mistake you really made by backtracking your changes until you hit the error again, then compare with the current solution and report here in a new answer.

Comment: @kriegaex After reading you're response I recreated the project from scratch but no success. It still throws errors. For you're reference I've added the new project with log in this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7U7tF2SDKJdSzJtUmhGc3EtaEk?usp=sharing).